# how to implement focus() on selected text box with in gridview

Tags: jquery

i have a text box "txtSales" with in the gridview "gvClientView",how to do focus of selected row index in different function as a name is $("#close").click(function() .

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
     $("table[id*=gvClientView] input[type=text][id*=txtSales]").blur(function() {
         alert($(this.val());//here i am getting value of selected text box
     });

     $("#close").click(function(){ //here i want to use focus of selected row of textbox in grid view });
 });
 </script>
```

Comment: try something like document.getElementByID("<%=TextBox1.ClientID%>").focus();

Comment: no i dont want to use document.getElementByID.please read question carefully and give the answer according to that

Comment: Sorry I thought i understood the question but.. I guess I do not understand the question :) ...

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the GridView expose any way to read the selected row in client side code, but if you say that in the `.blur()` you get proper textbox, just focus the last "blurred" textbox when clicking the button:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var lastBlurred = null;

    $("table[id*=gvClientView] input[type=text][id*=txtSales]").blur(function() {
        lastBlurred = this;
        alert($(this.val());//here i am getting value of selected text box
    });

    $("#close").click(function() {
        if (lastBlurred != null)
            lastBlurred.focus();
    });
});
```

Edit: to achieve what you want, you need to bind both `blur()` and `focus()` events:

```
$("table[id*=gvClientView] input[type=text][id*=txtSales]").bind("blur focus", function() {
        lastBlurred = this;
});
```

Quick [test case](http://jsfiddle.net/tr67v/) shows the logic itself is working.

Comment: i am getting null with in close function.how to solve this problem.let me know please

Comment: You mean `lastBlurred` is always null even after you focus certain textbox in the grid view?

Comment: yes i am getting null.do you know how to achieve solution of this problem

Comment: Do you see the alert showing with correct value before clicking the button?

Comment: yes,alert($(this.val());here i am getting value of selected text box

Comment: now focus has come,but when i am going to clear this text ,its showing object does not support this method.how to clear this text..please tell me

Comment: $("#close").click(function() {
           lastBlurred.focus();
            lastBlurred.val();
              instead of val we can use different technique for clear this txt.
           
            
    });

Comment: Change `lastBlurred.val()` to be `lastBlurred.value = "";` and it will work.

Comment: Cheers Jenifer, if this solved your problem feel free to accept the answer by ticking the V icon to the left. :)